# Unsure If I should do a seasonal difference in my dataset

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, acf-pacf, differencing

I'm doing my final project for my bachelor's on Time Series, I'm using a dataset for precipitation for São Paulo City here in Brazil.

My goal is to divide the dataset into training and testing and then compare the results against each other. I'm looking to use SARIMA as I believe it fits de data and context.

Data looked pretty much stationary to being with:
[image]

I did the ADF Test which confirmed what I thought:

Stats ADF: -4.506001282637859

p-value: 0.0001917879351290753

Critical Values: 1%: -3.4451642100030084 5%: -2.8680716196949327 10%: -2.5702491139112085

However, I understand that ADF only tests for the unit root, and it could be that you would still need to do some other types of transformations. And this is where I start having trouble and answers in forums have not been helpful so far. This is what my ACF and PACF look like without transformations to the series:

[image]

I have put many lags to show that basically, the decay on the ACF is really really slow, I'm showing 100 lags and still show many significant points we could use.

Also, I'm not sure what the ACF shapes represent here, am I correct to assume that it shows a lot of correlation every 12th (24th, 36th, and so on) lag, and the ones that are negative have basically no correlation (6th,18th and so on)? This would make sense considering rain patterns.

Does my original series benefits from a seasonal differentiation? Do you have any tips on where could I go from here? Maybe check residuals?